# Recover Deleted Partition on USB Stick

Tags: data-recovery, usb-storage, partition-recovery

I accidentally deleted everything off my (16GB Sony Micro Vault) USB memory Stick.

I ran **DISKPART /CLEAR** on the wrong drive.

How do I recover my data (approx. 14GB)?

Scanning with **Active@ Undelete 9.0** shows the following results:

**EFISECTOR (1:)  [Excellent]**

**Local Disk (3:) [Excellent]**

**Boot (2:)       [Good]**

Originally, there was only one visible volume on the the stick. My understanding is, there may also have been one or more hidden partitions.

What do I do now?

When I expand any of theses entries, none of them contain my actual data.

Answer (score 1):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is probably your best free/libre choice for recovering the whole partition. you can install it locally, or find it bundled with a number of live CDs including this one: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd

Remember, do not attempt to write the recovered data to the drive you are recovering from. you will have to recover the data elsewhere, and then copy it back. Otherwise you will overwrite the very data you are attempting to recover.

Some HowTo's:
http://thestarman.pcministry.com/testdisk.html
http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk

Answer (score 0):

You can simple recover data and partition using

Easeus partition recovery. It is a great tool which is capable of recovering even deleted partitions.

[More Info here](http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/)

Comment: Can I use it FREE or do I need to pay for it ?

Comment: There are tons of free alternatives that do exactly what the paid version of Easeus does.  Use the recovery program of your choice.

Comment: Its not free. But it is one of the best i have used